# How long will sealed chicken keep?

Tags: food-safety, chicken

For example if I seal chicken in the morning by cooking it on just the outside, is it safe to cook that night all the way through if kept refrigerated during the day?

Comment: Do you mean *seared* chicken? And what are you actually trying to do by cooking it partially in the morning and the rest of the way later?

Comment: Chicken lives by the same rules as all perishable food. Reference the Danger Zone and FAT TOM. All other information is extraneous.

Answer (score 6):

Searing chicken on the outside does *not* "seal" it. In fact, it is likely to bring the interior of the meat into the worst part of the danger zone (about 10-30° C above room temperature) and may actually *reduce* its safety factor.

If you seared it and put it *directly* back in the refrigerator, then it should still be under the 2-hour maximum for the temperature danger zone and safe to cook/eat. But be sure you cook it fully, up to the recommended 165° C; the previous searing doesn't count for anything, food-safety-wise.

If it sat around at room temperature after the searing for any significant length of time, throw it out.

Incidentally, if you want a good sear on any type of meat in addition to getting it properly cooked, the typical way to accomplish that is to either pop it into the oven for a bit after the initial sear, or to sear it *after* a slower-cooking method. I can't really see the point in searing a chicken several hours in advance.

Comment: I would also recommend searing after slow-cooking or baking on low temperature. This could be done in a pan or in the oven (turned to high heat).